# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener not blocking an array of urls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-webrequest

I am trying to block an array of urls based on user input. I have the url array in JSON format, but the sites are not actually being blocked when I navigate to them. If I use only one site, instead of an array, it does get blocked successfully. Here is the function.

```
function addListener(){
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
      function(){ return {cancel: true}; },
      {
        urls: blockedUrls()
      },
      ["blocking"]
    );
}
```

And here is my function blockedUrls.

```
var blockedUrls = function () {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(['block'], function(result) {
            if (typeof result.block === 'undefined') {
                //blocks is not yet set
                var jobj = ["*://www.whatever.com/*"];
                return [jobj[0]];
                console.log("not set");
            }
            else{
                var xt = JSON.parse(result.block);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(xt.urls));
                return JSON.stringify(xt.urls);
            } 
        });
        return ["*://www.whatever.com/*"];
}
```

The console.log does print out what I want, which is this (some were just used for testing obviously)

```
["doesntexist.com","*://www.yahoo.com/*","*://www.xbox.com/*","*://www.hello.com/*","*://www.es/*"]
```

And, if it helps, here is where the sites get initially set into chrome storage, from the variable request.newSites.

```
var jsonStr = '{"urls":["doesntexist.com"]}';

                var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

                //add url matching patterns to the urls from user input
                for (var i = 0; i < request.newSite.length; i++){
                    obj['urls'].push( '*://www.' + request.newSite[i] + '/*');
                }

                jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);


                chrome.storage.sync.set({'block': jsonStr}, function(){
                    addListener();
                });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function `blockedUrls` **always** returns `["*://www.whatever.com/*"]`, because the callback function of `chrome.storage.sync.get` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1) `chrome.storage.sync.get`'s callback function is **asynchronous**. Therefore, in your function `blockedUrls` the return value will always be `["*://www.whatever.com/*"]`, because the line `return ["*://www.whatever.com/*"];` will run before `chrome.storage.sync.get`'s callback function.

2) The second argument of `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` listener should be an object in the following form:
`{urls: theUrls}` where `theUrls` is an **Array** of strings, not a string.

Apart from that, you can take advantage of the fact that `chrome.storage` can store objects and arrays directly, so there is no need to stringify them.

Try with:

```
var obj = {urls: ['*://doesntexist.com/*']};

for (var i = 0, j = request.newSite.length; i < j; i++){
    obj.urls.push( '*://www.' + request.newSite[i] + '/*');
}

chrome.storage.sync.set({block: obj}, function(){
    addListener();
});

function addListener() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('block', function (result) {
        var myUrls = result.block || ["*://www.whatever.com/*"];
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(){
            return {cancel: true}
        },
        {urls: myUrls},
        ["blocking"] );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`chrome.storage.sync.get` is an asyncronous function. Therefor it will not return your url list.

What you probably meant to do was the following:

```
function addListener(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['block'], function(result) {
        let urls;
        if (typeof result.block === 'undefined') {
            //blocks is not yet set
            var jobj = ["*://www.whatever.com/*"];
            urls = [jobj[0]];
            console.log("not set");
        }
        else{
            var xt = JSON.parse(result.block);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(xt.urls));
            urls = JSON.stringify(xt.urls);
        } 
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
          function(){ return {cancel: true}; },
          {
            urls: urls
          },
          ["blocking"]
        );
    });
}
```