# urls are not blocking while working with chrome.webRequest api

Tags: javascript, chrome-webrequest

I have stored some urls in chrome.storage.sync like below......

```
sitesToBeBlocked: {
   "https://www.google.com/":"https://www.google.com/" ,
   "https://www.example.com/": "https://www.example.com/"
}
```

Now i am trying to block these urls using the code below.....

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "chrome extension",
  "description": ".............",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["/scripts/background/background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*"] ,
      "js": ["/scripts/content/jquery-3.6.0.js","/scripts/content/content-script.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": ["storage","unlimitedStorage","webRequest","webRequestBlocking","*://*/*"],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "/popup/popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      ............
    }
  },

  "options_ui": {
      "page": "/options/options.html",
      "open_in_tab": true
  },
  
 }
```

**background.js**

```
function isRequestCancelled(sitesArray, url){
    return sitesArray.includes(url);
}

function blockListener (details) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, (items)=>{
        var sitesArray = Object.keys(items['sitesToBeBlocked']);
        
        return { cancel: isRequestCancelled(sitesArray, details.url ) };
    });  
}
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( blockListener ,{ urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: [ 'main_frame' ] }, ['blocking'] );
```

**But URLs are not blocked**, I don't know what is the matter...
please help me to get the exact problem that i am facing ............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I figured out the problem in my code myself..**

Actually the problem here is that `chrome.storage.sync` 's callback is asynchronous fucntion. Due to which `chrome.webRequest` 's callback is terminated before `chrome.storage.sync` 's callback return.

**The solution can be,**

Put everything inside `chrome.storage.sync` 's callback, so that every function will return after `chrome.storage.sync` 's callback executes.

**Finally I have fixed this issue with the modified code below....**

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(null,(items)=>{

  function isRequestCancelled(sitesArray, url){
    return sitesArray.includes(url);
  }

  function blockListener (details) {
     var sitesArray = Object.keys(items['sitesToBeBlocked']);
     return { cancel: isRequestCancelled(sitesArray, details.url ) };
  }
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( blockListener ,{ urls: [" 
  <all_urls>"], types: [ 'main_frame' ] }, ['blocking'] ); 

});
```

Actual clue is got from [related query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832803/chrome-webrequest-onbeforerequest-addlistener-not-blocking-an-array-of-urls)